# How to remove column headers in js for a table set in html

Tags: javascript

I have defined my table in html. I destroy the DataTable and reinitialize it based on certain conditions. However, before I destroy and reinitialize my DataTable for few seconds just the column headers are clubbed and rendered. This is happening because I'm creating my DataTable in html. Is there a way to remove these column headers and re-add them before DataTable initialization.

Comment: Please share your code. What you have tried and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Can hide or remove the header row as needed. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: I have created table in html like this
  <table id="funTable" class="responsive fun-table-display">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="fun-column-one">

Comment: <div class="fun-header-txt">fun Begin Date</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="fun-column-two">
                                <div class="plans-service-loc-hist-header-txt">fun End Date</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="fun-column-three">
                                <div class="fun-header-txt">fun Address</div>
                            </th>                           
                        </tr>

Comment: </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>

And then I destroy it and re initialize it before every DB call.
  $tableElem.DataTable().clear().destroy();

As I destroy the DataTable in refresh method before reintialize and destroy for few seconds the Grid renders just the column headers and it is awkward. How can I fix this? Yes hiding the header row is allowed.